# PHP undefined indexというエラー

Tags: php, mysql

MySQLのuserというテーブルにname, pwといったカラムを作っています。
以下のPHPを実行するとUndefined index: name
というエラーが出るのですが、原因がわかりません。
pwは正しく判定出来ています。

```
$ps=$db->prepare("SELECT pw FROM user WHERE email= :u_mail");
$ps->bindParam(":u_mail", $m);
$ps->execute();
if($ps->rowCount()>0){
   $r=$ps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   if($r['pw']===md5($p)){
       $_SESSION['user']=$r['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
SELECT pw FROM user WHERE email= :u_mail
ではなく
SELECT pw, name FROM user WHERE email= :u_mail
にすれば大丈夫でした。

Answer (score 1):

初めまして。お力になれるかわかりませんが、現段階で気になったことを書かせていただきます。

Undefined index: name
は、$r連想配列のキーnameがないことを表示しているものと思います。

```
$ps=$db->prepare("SELECT pw FROM user WHERE email= :u_mail");
$ps->bindParam(":u_mail", $m);
$ps->execute();
if($ps->rowCount()>0){
$r=$ps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// ここで$rのキーがあるか確認
print var_export($r);

if($r['pw']===md5($p)){
$_SESSION['user']=$r['name'];
```

printで画面に表示されるかは、実装の仕方によってことなります。
var_export()の結果を標準出力に表示した際に、
$ps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);の返り値が判明します。

一度やってみてください。